# instinct for bluntness bordering on confrontation

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've read (by web search) dictionary meanings of `blunt`, `border` (could not find `border on` specifics), certainly I hope I know what confrontation means. Still the phrase "instinct for bluntness bordering on confrontation" in acticle about founder of Amazon Inc. does not seem meaningfull. What is its' meaning?

Comment: Bordering on = very close to a boundary. Nearly crossing a boundary that would create a confrontation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the verb "to border", meaning "to be close to". It is being used in an idiom 
"X bordering on Y", where X and Y are usually abstract nouns.

It means that the founder of Amazon is so very blunt that he is almost confrontational.